# Page size is changed, I want to lose div (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

```js
 if ($(window).width() <= 480) {

            $(".content").hide();

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

İt's not working. Please Help.

Comment: how this going to work you don't have any `content` element?

Comment: how do you run the function on width? What triggers it? Or only on load?

Answer (score 1):

it seems you want to see this in `.resize()` event:

```
$(function(){ // <----doc ready.
    $(window).resize(function(){ //<----resize event bound on window.
      if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
          $(".content").hide(); 
      }
    }).resize(); // <----triggered the event on doc ready.
});
```

#### [See this in action here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ncvx0101/)

Answer (score 0):

Show and hide .content block on $(window).resize() and $(document).ready() events.
Example for $(window).resize():

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".content").toggle($(window).width() >= 480);
});
```

Comment: Strange.
May be I don't understand your problem correctly. 
Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/aekvj8qj/